# Communication between an android c native application and an android application

Tags: android, inter-process-communicat

I want to ask if someone know how to make communicate a native c android application and an classic java android application, the native c android application running in background.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is download the [android-ndk available here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). It comes with it's own documentation which will be available here: [android-ndk path]/documentation.html, You can also find information in the android-ndk link above.

If you're anything like me you'll need as much help as you can get developing a JNI bridge. I had to find these resource myself but they were invaluable to me. See below for JNI information:

[Table Of Contents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)

[Methods (older resource)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/functions.html#97032)

[Methods (newer resource)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html)

[Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html)

[Reference](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniIX.html)

You can integrate your NDK/C++ code and debug it from Eclipse using [Sequoyah](http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php) and [CDT (C/C++ Development Tooling)](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

More specifically to answer your question - You can use a service as a wrapper around your native code if you require the native code to run in the background. This will enable you to push information to the native code using the OS's intent mechanism in a fifo structure.